# Save ini file with comments

Tags: php, text

I need to store some data in an ini file, and I have run into a problem. It is not hard to read the dat from the ini file, as php provides a built in function for that:

```
<?php
ini_parse();
?>
```

The problem is that I need to save data to the INI file, while (preferably) preserving commments. I would especially like to preserve this comment at the top:

```
;<?php die(); ?>
```

Im sure you can guess the reason for this, but in case you can't figure it out, I don't want this file to be requested directly. I would just like to read the INI values out of it using another php script.

However if there is not a way to preserve the comments, I still need to store data into the INI file, so I still need a class to save data to the INI file.

Does anyone know of a class that might do this?

Comment: Why not just place the INI file in a directory that the outside world can't access?

Comment: Do you enable the PHP interpreter for .ini files so you can use PHP to prevent .ini files from being executed?

Comment: The conditions of this script make it perferrable to protect the file using the method above, and even if it was protected, I would still need to save the data to the file anyways.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This comment won't help you protect your file from being read in web browser, unless you configure your server to parse ini files as php source. Better idea is to place this file outside webroot, in password protected directory or configure one directory not to serve ini files.

As for writing data, this function will do for simple arrays:

```
function write_ini_file($file, array $options){
    $tmp = '';
    foreach($options as $section => $values){
        $tmp .= "[$section]\n";
        foreach($values as $key => $val){
            if(is_array($val)){
                foreach($val as $k =>$v){
                    $tmp .= "{$key}[$k] = \"$v\"\n";
                }
            }
            else
                $tmp .= "$key = \"$val\"\n";
        }
        $tmp .= "\n";
    }
    file_put_contents($file, $tmp);
    unset($tmp);
}
```

So array like this:

```
$options = array(
    'ftp_cfg' => array(
        'username' => 'user',
        'password' => 'pass',
        'hostname' => 'localhost',
        'port'     => 21
    ),
    'other_cfg' => array(
        'banned_emails' => array(
            'example@example.com',
            'spam@spam.gov'
        ),
        'ini_version' => 1.1
    )
);
```

Will be turned to:

```
[ftp_cfg]
username = "user"
password = "pass"
hostname = "localhost"
port = "21"

[other_cfg]
banned_emails[0] = "example@example.com"
banned_emails[1] = "spam@spam.gov"
ini_version = "1.1"
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Just what I needed! Even though it does not maintain comments, I was not really expecting that to happen.

Comment: Even if you  use it for really simple arrays -- it should at least escape double quotes.

Answer (score 0):

If your goal is to preserve the `die()`, the only way I know is to put it into a quoted value.

```
fake_value = "<?php die(); ?>";
```

I don't think it's possible to preserve comments using `parse_ini_file()`. You'd have to build your own parser for that. The User Contributed Notes on the [manual page](http://www.php.net/parse_ini_file) may be of help.

Comment: This really does not help me, as you have provided no function, or even advice, to give me any Idea of how I should write INI values to a file.

Answer (score 0):

With an `.htaccess` file, you can deny the access to this file.

Comment: Please keep your answers in English.